# Gson - getAsBoolean of null JsonElement

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to get a field from JsonObject in that way:

`myJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("first").getAsJsonObject.("two").get("booleanValue").getAsBoolean();`

This works fine when the JsonObject has the whole fields that I try to get.
My problem is when `"booleanValue"` returns me null and I am getting `NullPointerException` for trying to `getAsBoolean`. Of course I can check if it null before trying to `getAsBoolean` but I am wondering if there is any prettier solution for this case.

- I don't control the json content (it is from service that isn't in my responsibility).

Hope you understand my problem..

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary checking for this

```
myJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("first").getAsJsonObject.("two").get("booleanValue") == null ? "return something you want or simply null " : myJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("first").getAsJsonObject.("two").get("booleanValue").getAsBoolean();
```